# Using Nest inside NestList

Tags: programming, functions, functional-style

I need results like this:

```
{Cos[Cos[x]], Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]],Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]]]], 
 Sin[Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]]]]], ... }
```

I've tried to use `Nest` inside `NestList`, but failed:

```
NestList[Sin, Nest[Cos, x, 2], 3]

(* {Cos[Cos[x]], Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]], Sin[Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]]], 
 Sin[Sin[Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]]]]}  *)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
n = 5; flist = {Composition @@ ConstantArray[Cos, 2], Sin};
ComposeList[PadRight[flist, n, flist], 1]
{1, Cos[Cos[1]], Sin[Cos[Cos[1]]], Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[1]]]]], 
 Sin[Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[1]]]]]], Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[1]]]]]]]]}
```

Comment: You are so good at manipulating lists.

Comment: I like this method but your code seems pointlessly baroque.  Why not use `flist = {Cos@Cos@#&, Sin}` ?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: it extends nicely to something like `Composition @@@ {ConstantArray[Cos, 3], ConstantArray[Sin, 2]};`, to use kguler's example. I was already expecting someone else to use `Nest[]`, also, as kguler did.

Comment: I think you should include that in your answer; then it will make sense.

Answer (score 4):

```
 iterate[f1_, f2_, x_, n_] := 
    Rest@FoldList[({f1[#1], f2[#1]}[[Mod[#2, 2, 1]]]) &, x, Range[n]];
 iterate[Cos[Cos[#]] &, Sin, x, 5]
 (* ==> {Cos[Cos[x]], Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]], Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]]]], Sin[Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]]]]], Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]]]]]]]}*)
```

EDIT: Just learned about `ComposeList` (thanks J.M.!). Here is a variation using `ComposeList` and `Nest`:

```
iterate2[f1_, steps1_, f2_, steps2_, x_, n_] := 
  With[{indices = Mod[Range[n], 2, 1]}, 
  Rest@ComposeList[{Nest[f1, #, steps1] &, Nest[f2, #, steps2] &}[[indices]], x]];
iterate2[Cos, 3, Sin, 2, x, 4]
(* ==> {Cos[Cos[Cos[x]]], Sin[Sin[Cos[Cos[Cos[x]]]]], Cos[Cos[Cos[Sin[Sin[Cos[Cos[Cos[x]]]]]]]], Sin[Sin[Cos[Cos[Cos[Sin[Sin[Cos[Cos[Cos[x]]]]]]]]]]}  *)
```

Comment: I don't believe you intended to use the `Cos@Cos` construction...

Comment: @J.M. Thank you J.M.; you are right, I copy/pasted the wrong lines.

Comment: Nice! I'd like to remind you that `Mod[]` is listable, so `Mod[Range[n], 2, 1]` works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
With[{n = 3}, Flatten[Rest[NestList[{Cos[Cos[#]], Sin[Cos[Cos[#]]]} &@Last[#] &, {x}, n]]]]

(* out: {Cos[Cos[x]], Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]], Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]]]], 
         Sin[Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]]]]], 
         Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]]]]]]], 
         Sin[Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[Sin[Cos[Cos[x]]]]]]]]]} *)
```

Comment: your codes works well for my example, and I think it can be simplified as NestList[Sin[Cos[Cos[#]]] &, {x}, n]. Anyway, I like it very much. But If the number of succesive Cos is very large(e.g., 10^3), you like to use NestList[Compose[Sin, Nest[Cos, #, 10^3]] &, x, 3] or anything better?